# SQL Server backup only those stored procedures whose object definition is modified

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am having a scenario where I need to create a backup of database which contains huge data in GBs. Once the full backup is done I am trying to optimize it using partial backup or backing up only those SP's whose object definition is modified.

One way I can think of is comparing through Object definition date, say past 7 days.

Can you please let me know better way which I can achieve this?

Comment: Look at the [Differential Backups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526.aspx)

Comment: `mysql`, `sql-server`, or Oracle (`plsql`)?  I think you need to remove 2 out of those 3 tags.

Comment: Stored Procedures do not contain data, only code.  In any normal DB your data should be changing a ***lot*** more than your code.

Comment: Backup strategies doesn't look that way. "backing up only those SP's whose object definition is modified". Backup strategies include, full backups, differential backups, file and file-group backups and transaction log backups. A typical strategy would be: 1 full backup every sunday, 1 differential backup every night, 1 transaction log backup every hour. Ask your DBA.

Comment: If all you really, truly want is to backup SP's, you could create a separate filegroup.  Then drop/recreate the SP's in the new filegroup.  From there, you would perform a [filegroup backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189906(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: @DMason, you cannot choose where to store a stored procedure definition. Stored procedure definitions are always stored in system tables and those tables are on the primary file on the primary file group.

Comment: I stand corrected.  You are right, @JesúsLópez.  Some db's are designed with nothing in the `PRIMARY` filegroup except system objects, which (as noted above) includes stored proc definitions.  If @abhijeetdhumal was inclined, he/she could create one or more filegroups, move data and indexes to the new filegroup(s), and change the default filegroup to something other than PRIMARY.  A filegroup backup of PRIMARY should be pretty slim.

Answer (score 2):

You do not back up databases that way. You back up the data in the database first and foremost. Objects are all backed up, you can't choose not to back up one table either.  You do a full back up on a schedule (like once a week) and then differential backups nightly and then transaction log backups roughly every 15 minutes. Frankly the fact that you are asking this question tells me your company needs to hire a dba to protect its data.

Next, stored procs shoudl be in source control like any other code. You can tell what the current version is the same way you tell the current version of any code. If you need to restore only one, you can do it from teh source control repository. This does require that you have procedures that do not permit developers to push code to other servers beyond dev and the build team or managers who do have the rights will only push from the source controlled version.

Answer (score 0):

Before optimizing anything in backups, you should really know what are your Recovery Point Objective and Recovery Time Objective -- meaning basically how long your system can be down and how much data you can lose. That's what you should use then to plan your backups.

Comment: Here's one link, the accidental DBA. There's several chapters for backups. Maybe it helps: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/accidental-dba/